# How to put php variable inside to_tsquery_partial() function Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I have question about `to_tsquery_partial()` function in postgresql, I want to put php variable that reads user input inside this function. I have a problem with  syntax, I've tried many times but nothing works. Can you help me please?. Here is the query:

```
$query='SELECT * FROM planet AS a,to_tsquery_partial(\'{$user}\') AS query
WHERE ts_road @@ query';
```

Thankx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to postgress, just vanialla php. You are inserting that variable into the string incorrectly. You have 2 options:

Use double quotes:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM planet AS a,to_tsquery_partial('$user') AS query WHERE ts_road @@ query";
```

Use single quotes and concatenate:

```
$query='SELECT * FROM planet AS a,to_tsquery_partial(\'' . $user . '\') AS query WHERE ts_road @@ query';
```

This explains things more in depth: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: First thankx for your help, I tried that but it's not working, I still get no result !!

Comment: if you `var_dump` the `$query`, does it look like it is supposed to? If you run that query directly on the database (with something like sequelPro or just from the cli), do you get a result? The actual execution of the query is not in your code snippet, so there is not much we can tell about it... (and I have zero experience with postgres, so I probably wouldn't be able to help anyway, but someone else may)

Comment: I tried the second and it's working but the rest of query don't have correct syntax

Comment: You help me soo much, thankx :) just I must figure out what this happend

Comment: That seems like a problem with the query then. Perhaps you should formulate a new question, but as far as I can tell you now know "How to put php variable inside to_tsquery_partial() function"

Comment: Yes I think. Ok I will formulate my question. Thankx so much :D

Comment: the problem that query is too long. There is a part of it: $query='SELECT * FROM planet AS a,to_tsquery_partial(\'' . $user . '\') AS query WHERE ts_road @@ query 
 UNION 

 SELECT * FROM road  AS a,to_tsquery_partial(\'' . $user . '\') AS query WHERE ts_road @@ query .....';

Comment: I can't help you with postgres. You really should post a new question describing your new problem!